# Qtip JQuery tooltip library - Only the right hand side corners are showing rounded

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

When I specify rounded corners for my qtip tooltip only the right hand side are rounded, and the left hand side have notches cut in the corners where the rounded corner should be.

This shows up on at least firefox and IE.

This is the code I'm using

```
$('#test').qtip({
   content: 'test',
   show: 'click',
   hide: 'unfocus',
   style: {
       width: 200,
       color: 'black',
       textAlign: 'center',
       border: {
          width: 15,
          radius: 8,
          color: '#6699CC'
       }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine for me, check here

[link text](http://jsbin.com/amoko3/3/edit)